# What is the best statistical method to compare case fatality rates of 17 years for 2 different states?

Tags: epidemiology, odds-ratio, methodology

I have [Case Fatality Rates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Case_fatality_rate) (deaths per 100 cases) for 2 different states receiving different treatments for 17 years.

What is the best statistical method to compare Case Fatality Rates ?

The data are like this

```
Year   St.1 Cases  St.1 Deaths St.1 CFR St.2 Cases St.2 Deaths  State2 CFR  
1994    1836        383         20.86     583        121         20.75
1995    1246        257         20.63    1126        227         20.16
1996    1450        263         18.14     896        179         19.98
1997    2953        407         13.78     351         76         21.65
1998    1161        149         12.83     1061       195         18.55
1999    2924        434         14.84     1371       275         20.06
2000    1729        169          9.77     1170       253         21.62
2001    1888        275         14.57     1005      199          19.80  
2002    919         178          19.37      604      133         22.02   
2003    865        142         16.42      1124      237         21.09
2004    1543       131          8.49      1030      228         22.14
2005    2887       336         11.64      6061     1500         24.75
2006    1484       108         7.28       2320     528          22.76
2007    1592       75          4.71       3024     645          21.33
2008    1920       53          2.76       3012     537          17.83
2009    1477       40          2.71       3073     556          18.09
2010    1534      26           1.69       3540     494          13.95
```