# Comparing fatality rates

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, epidemiology

I have [case fatality rates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Case_fatality_rate) (deaths per 100 cases) for 2 different states receiving different treatments for 17 years.

What is the best statistical method to compare them? Relative risk, odds ratio, plain time series analysis, ...?

The data is like this:

```
Year   St.1 Cases  St.1 Deaths St.1 CFR St.2 Cases St.2 Deaths  State2 CFR  
1994    1836        383         20.86     583      121          20.75
1995    1246        257         20.63     1126     227          20.16
1996    1450        263         18.14     896      179          19.98
1997    2953        407         13.78     351      76           21.65
1998    1161        149         12.83     1061     195          18.55
1999    2924        434         14.84     1371     275          20.06
2000    1729        169         9.77      1170     253          21.62
2001    1888        275         14.57     1005     199          19.80  
2002    919         178         19.37     604      133          22.02   
2003    865         142         16.42     1124     237          21.09
2004    1543        131         8.49      1030     228          22.14
2005    2887        336         11.64     6061     1500         24.75
2006    1484        108         7.28      2320     528          22.76
2007    1592        75          4.71      3024     645          21.33
2008    1920        53          2.76      3012     537          17.83
2009    1477        40          2.71      3073     556          18.09
2010    1534        26          1.69      3540     494          13.95
```

Comment: It seems like this DrWho has asked and gotten answers for this exact question a number of times: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11917/what-is-the-best-statistical-method-to-compare-case-fatality-rates-of-17-years-fo, http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/8358/how-to-assess-effect-of-intervention-in-one-state-versus-another-using-annual-cas , http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/8187/how-to-assess-effect-of-intervention-in-one-state-versus-another-using-annual-dea
It would be helpful to know why the previous answers were not satisfactory.